# Implementation of Planar Point Location using slabs

Tags: algorithm, location, point

I am looking into a Planar Point Location, and right now thinking about make use of The Slabs approach.

I've read through a couple of articles:

- [Planar Point Location Using Persistent Search Trees](http://users.cs.fiu.edu/~giri/teach/6405/s04/SarnakTarjanCACM86.pdf)
- [Persistent Data Structures](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.854/06/scribe/s2-persistent.pdf)
- [Point location on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location)

I understand the concept behind a persistent balanced binary search tree, but let's omit them in this question, I don't really care about extra storage space overhead. The thing with the articles is they are discussing how speed can be improved, but don't explain basic stuff. For example:

Could you please correct me if I am wrong:

> 1. We draw a line across all intersections.
> 2. Now, we have slabs that are split by the segments at different angles.
> 3. Every intersection with any line is considered a vertex.
> 4. Slabs are sorted by order in a binary search tree (let's omit a partially persistent bst)
> 5. Somehow, sectors are sorted in those respective BST's, even though the segments dividing them are almost always at an angle. Does each node has to carry a definition of area?

Please refer to this example image:

[image]

Questions:

1. How would I actually figure out if the point lies in Node c and not in Node b? Is it somehow via area?
2. Do I instead need arrange my nodes to contain information about the segments? I could then check if the query point lies above a segment (if that's how I should determine my sectors)? If so, would I then search through a Polygon List after, to see which polygon this particular segment belongs to?
3. Maybe I need to store BST for each line and not a slab?
4. Would I then have to look at 2 BST's belonging to line on the left, and the 2nd one of the line to the right from the vertex? I could then sort the vertexes by y coordinate in each tree and return the y coordinate of a vertex (the end of a segment) right below my query point. Having done this for left and right line, I would then do a comparison to see if the names of the segment those vertexes come from actually match.
5. However, this will not give me the right answer, since even if the names do match, I might be below or above the segment (if I am close to it). Also, this implies I have to do 3 binary searches (1 for lines, 1 for the y-coordinate on left line, 1 for the right one), and the books says I only need to do 2 searches (1 for slab, 2nd for sector).

Could someone please point me in the direction to do it?

I probably just missed some essential thought or something.

**Edit:**

[Here](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~michiel/lecturenotes/ALGGEOM/pointlocation.pdf) is another good article, that explains the solution to the problem, however, I don't quite understand how I would achieve the following:

*"Consider any query point q ∈ R2. To find the face of G that contains q, we first use binary search with the x-coordinate of q to find the vertical slab s that contains q. Given s, we use binary search with the y-coordinate of q to find the edges of Es between which q lies. "*

How exactly to find those 2 edges? Is it as simple as checking if the point lies below the segment? However, this seems like a complicated check to do (and expensive), as we descend down the tree, inspecting the other nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this was asked a year ago so I guess you're not going to be around to accept the answer.  It's a fun question, though, so here goes anyway...

- Yes, you can divide the plane into slabs using vertical lines through every intersection.  The important result is that all line segments that touch a slab will go all the way through, and the order of those line segments will be the same across the entire slab.
- In each slab, you make a binary search tree of those line segments, ordered by their order in the slab.  The areas that you call "nodes" are the leaves of the tree, and the line segments are the internal nodes.  I will call the leaves "areas" to avoid ambiguity.  Since the order of the line segments is the same across the entire slab, the order in this tree is valid for every x coordinate in the slab.
- to determine the area that contains any point, you find the slab that contains the point, and then do a simple search in the BST to find the area.
- Lets say you're looking for point C, and you're at the node in slab 2 that contains (x2,y2) - (x3,y4). Determine whether C is above or below this line segment, and then take that branch in the tree.

For example, if C is (cx,cy) then the y coordinate of the segment at x=cx is:

testy = ((cx-x2)/(x3-x2)) * (y4-y2) + y2

If cy < testy, then take the upward branch, otherwise take the downward branch. (assuming positive Y goes downward).

When you get to a leaf, that's the area that contains C.  You're done.

Now... Making a whole new tree for every slab takes a lot of space, since you can have N^2 intersection points and therefore N^2 slabs.  Storing a separate tree in every slab would take O(N^3) space.

Using, say, persistent red-black trees, however, the slabs can actually share a lot of nodes.  Using a simple purely functional implementation like Chris Okasaki's red-black tree takes O(log N) space per intersection for a total of O(N^2*log N) space.

I seem to remember that there is also a constant-space-per-change persistent red-black tree that would give you O(N^2), but I don't have a reference.

Note that for most real-life scenarios there are closer to O(N) intersections, because lines don't cross very much, but it's still nice to save the space by using a persistent tree.